# How to know that all Celery tasks are completed?

Tags: celery, celery-task

I am iterating here through all city and creating celery tasks(city_explore) asynchronously. I need to update status as "Explore Completed" in db after completion of all tasks. If it was normal function it could have been done easily but how to do this when tasks are running in celery ?? How would i know when all tasks are completed for each city and update the status in db ?? Please Help.

Here is the respective code

```
cities = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for city in cities:
    city_explore.delay(name, distance)

@app.task
def city_explore(name, dis):
    explorer(name, dis)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could do it that way, but then you have to code polling of the task statuses... A more idiomatic approach would be to use [Celery Workflows](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html). A Chord primitive would probably be good enough for you.